# each + setinterval +addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Подскажите, как запустить бесконечный цикл добавления у убирания класса?

делаю свечки.
каждые 2 секунды, свечка должна менять класс, а через 1 секунду - убирать его.

На текущий момент js такой -

```
$(function(){
var one = $('div.one'),
    two = $('div.two'),
    three = $('div.three'),
    four = $('div.four'),
    five = $('div.five'),
    six = $('div.six'),
    seven = $('div.seven');

    $('button.start').on('click', function () {

        $('div.circle').each(function () {
            setInterval($(this).addClass('active'), 1000);
        });

    });});
```

Подскажите что сделать, чтобы было как заявлено выше?

Comment: тоесть раз в 2 секунды добавляеться класс актив и через секунду после его добавления он должен убраться ?

Comment: Да, все правильно)

Answer (score 2):

Кажется так)

```js
let candle = document.querySelectorAll('.candle');
let on = false;
let interval; // Будем хранить здесь интервал, чтобы прервать, если захочется.
document.getElementById('on').addEventListener('click', function(){
  on = !on; // Воскл. знак переворачивает значение. false станет true, а true → false
  this.textContent = on ? "OFF" : "ON";
  if( on ){ // Если включили
    let curr = 0; // Индекс текущей свечки
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      candle[curr].classList.add('active');
      setTimeout(function(){
        candle[curr].classList.remove('active');
        // Увелививаем индекс на единицу, если есть куда расти. Иначе - сбрасываем на 0
        curr = (curr == candle.length - 1) ? 0 : curr + 1;
      }, 1000); // Через секунду отключаем
    }, 2000); // Раз в 2 секунды переключаем
  } else { // Если on оказался false
    clearInterval(interval);
    candle.forEach(function(e){
      e.classList.remove('active');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
/* Ненужные декорации; В реальной жизни не надо так делать - нагружает CPU */
body {
  background-color: #22262b;
}
.candle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #cca, #fff, #997);
  margin: 50px 10px;
}
.candle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: -2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #cca, #fff, #997);
}
.candle.active::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 37px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: -37px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#ff0 20%, #f36700 70%, #990);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: 0.2s linear light infinite;
}

@keyframes light {
  0% { transform: rotate(3deg) translateX(1px) scale(1,1.1) }
 50% { transform: rotate(-3deg) translateX(-1px) scale(1.1,1) }
100% { transform: rotate(3deg) translateX(1px) }
}

#on {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px; right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="candle"></div>
<div class="candle"></div>
<div class="candle"></div>
<div class="candle"></div>
<div class="candle"></div>
<div class="candle"></div>
<div class="candle"></div>

<button id="on">ON</button>
```

Перевод на jQuery, который здесь не особо сокращает код:

```js
let $candle = $('.candle');
let on = false;
let interval = null;
$('#on').on('click', function(){
  on = !on;
  $(this).text( on ? "OFF" : "ON" );
  if( on ){
    let curr = 0;
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      $candle.eq(curr).addClass('active');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $candle.eq(curr).removeClass('active');
        curr = curr == $candle.length - 1 ? 0 : curr + 1;
      }, 1000);
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    $candle.each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #22262b;
}
.candle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #cca, #fff, #997);
  margin: 50px 10px;
}
.candle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: -2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #cca, #fff, #997);
}
.candle.active::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 37px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: -37px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#ff0 20%, #f36700 70%, #990);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: 0.2s linear light infinite;
}

@keyframes light {
  0% { transform: rotate(3deg) translateX(1px) scale(1,1.1) }
 50% { transform: rotate(-3deg) translateX(-1px) scale(1.1,1) }
100% { transform: rotate(3deg) translateX(1px) }
}

#on {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px; right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="candle"></div>
<div class="candle"></div>
<div class="candle"></div>
<div class="candle"></div>
<div class="candle"></div>
<div class="candle"></div>
<div class="candle"></div>

<button id="on">ON</button>
```

P.s. можно было сделать через один интервал раз в секунду, но пришлось бы добавить доп проверки - включать или выключать.

Comment: Отличный ответ!